# Unable to run a loop using while

Tags: c++

I have written this code:

```
int sum,number;
sum=0;
number=1;

while(number<=11)
{
    sum=sum+number;
    cout << sum;
    number++;
}
cout << "The sum of the fist 11 is" cout << sum;
```

It dosent compile and gives the error:

```
17  37  C:\cprograms\main.cpp   [Error] expected ';' before 'cout'
```

I am unsable to understand what I am doing wrong?

I placed a `;` after the while loop end, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Abdullah it didnt' work

Comment: You need either a semicolon ";" after your string literal or replace 2nd "cout" with "<<"

Comment: Posted correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace your last line with

```
cout << "The sum of the fist 11 is" << sum;
```

Comment: a question is always genuine for the one who has asked :D , enjoy

Answer (score 1):

Change following line:

```
cout << "The sum of the fist 11 is" cout << sum;
```

to

```
cout << "The sum of the fist 11 is";
cout << sum;
```

Comment: But how can i concatinate the sum with the string??

Comment: The content is getting concatenated into `cout` which is effectively getting displayed on to the console. Alternate way of writing the same thing is: `cout << "The sum of the fist 11 is" << sum;`

Comment: Why split it into two lines? Just remove the erroneous `cout` from the middle.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That's one way to do it. I think my fix was more easy to understand for the error message posted: `expected ';' before 'cout'`

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. Works,

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int sum, number;
    sum=0;
    number=1;

    while(number<=11)
    {
        sum = sum + number;
        cout<<sum<<endl;
        number++;
    }
    cout << "The sum of the fist 11 is "<<sum;
}
```

In a statement you don't write `cout` multiple times, just `<<`